# virtual-nodes-factor for akka cluster nodes in the akka cluster configuration

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Configuration for Consistent Hashing router for normal actors

akka.actor.deployment {

```
/parent/router27 {

  router = consistent-hashing-group

  routees.paths = 
          ["/user/workers/w1", "/user/workers/w2", "/user/workers/w3"]

  virtual-nodes-factor = 10

}
```

}

Configuration consistent hashing in case of Cluster

akka.actor.deployment {

```
 /statsService/workerRouter {

   router = consistent-hashing-group

   nr-of-instances = 100

   routees.paths = ["/user/statsWorker"]

   cluster {

     enabled = on

     allow-local-routees = on

     use-role = compute

   }

 }
```

}

In the above cluster configuration Can we add this `virtual-nodes-factor = 10` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but under router configuration, and that is default value